# Determining the last column so that the resulting matrix is an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

> Determine the last column so that the resulting matrix is an orthogonal
>   matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & ? \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & ? \\ 0 & \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{6}} & ? \end{bmatrix}$$

Can anyone please provide **hints** to solve this?

Comment: Use gram Schmidt

Comment: @Geronimo You mean I need to find $V_1,V_2$ and then find $V_3$?

Comment: Probably post something in the morning. But its like midnight.

Comment: @Geronimo Not yet

Comment: No im saying i will post something tomorrow however its midnight for me.

Comment: @Geronimo ohhh.. its okay.

Comment: @Geronimo Can you post the answer now

Comment: i've posted a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} &  ?\\  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & ?\\\ 0 &  \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} & ? \end{bmatrix}  $$

Ok if you take $ a_{1} \times a_{2} = a_{3} $ it produces an orthogonal vector.

$$ a_{1} \times a_{2} = \begin{vmatrix} i & j & k  \\ a_{11}&  a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \end{vmatrix} $$

$$ a_{1} \times a_{2} = \begin{vmatrix} a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{22} & a_{23} \end{vmatrix} i  - \begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{23} \end{vmatrix}j + \begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{vmatrix}k $$

expanding this we get

$$ a_{1} \times a_{2} = (a_{12}a_{23}-a_{13}a_{22} )i - (a_{11}a_{23}-a_{13}a_{23})j + ( a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21})k $$

writing this out now

$$a_{1} \times a_{2} = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}-0\cdot\frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}})i  - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}-0\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}})j + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}})k $$

Getting rid of stuff

$$a_{1} \times a_{2} = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}})i  - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}})j + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}})k $$

More cleaning up

$$a_{1} \times a_{2} = (\frac{2}{2\sqrt{3}})i  - (\frac{2}{2\sqrt{3}})j + (\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{3}}- \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}})k $$
More cleaning

$$a_{1} \times a_{2} = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})i  - (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})j + (\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}})k $$

Checking if they are orthogonal

we need that 
$$ a_{1} \cdot (a_{1} \times a_{2}) =0 , a_{2} \cdot (a_{1} \times a_{2}) =0$$

$$a_{1} \cdot (a_{1} \times a_{2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}) + (0)\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} $$

Note that they are opposite  this is zero.

$$a_{2} \cdot (a_{1} \times a_{2}) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}})(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}) + (\frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}})(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}) + (\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}) $$

we have

$$a_{2} \cdot (a_{1} \times a_{2}) =  (\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})+ (\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}) =0 $$

Done, finally

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} &  \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}\\\ 0 &  \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} \end{bmatrix}  $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $[ x \ y \ z]$ be the vector you are looking for, then it must satisfy
$$x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+z (0)= 0$$
which is $y = - x$ and
$$x \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} -y \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}+z \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} = 0$$
which is $z = \frac{1}{2}y - \frac{1}{2}x$. Using $y = -x$ in $z = \frac{1}{2}y - \frac{1}{2}x$, we get
$$z = -x$$
So the vector you are looking for has the form $[x, \ -x, \ -x]$
Choose $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ (for example), we get $[\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}]$, which is a possible last column.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: remember that the cross product of two vectors of length 3 is orthogonal to both argument vectors and that an orthogonal matrix's columns are themselves an orthogonal set of vectors…

Comment: Why scale at all? The two known columns are orthogonal unit vectors, which makes their cross product nice.

Comment: @amd I do many of my calculations when answering questions in my head. For these purposes it is nice if I can get whole numbers to manipulate, but since I know the unit vectors are there and you said it, you'll have your way...

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is orthogonal if all the column vectors are unit vectors and any two columns have dot product zero. Now write the unknown last column as $(x\ y\ z)^T$.  You will get two equations when when you insist it be orthogonal to the known first and second columns.

So solve a system of 2 equations an $x,y,z$. There will be infinitely many solutions. Now the condition on length will bring down the solutions to 2 (a vector and its negative).

Answer (score 0):

Using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
>>> M = Matrix([[1/sqrt(2),  1/sqrt(6), x],
                [1/sqrt(2), -1/sqrt(6), y],
                [        0,  2/sqrt(6), z]])
>>> simplify(M.T * M)
Matrix([
[                1,                       0,       sqrt(2)*(x + y)/2],
[                0,                       1, sqrt(6)*(x - y + 2*z)/6],
[sqrt(2)*(x + y)/2, sqrt(6)*(x - y + 2*z)/6,      x**2 + y**2 + z**2]])
```

Thus, we obtain the following system of equations

$$\begin{aligned} x + y &= 0\\ x + z &= 0\\ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 &= 1\end{aligned}$$

which is easy to solve. Alternatively, we can take the $2$ known columns (which are orthonormal), form a $3 \times 2$ matrix, transpose it and then compute its null space:

```
>>> (Matrix([[1/sqrt(2),  1/sqrt(6)],
             [1/sqrt(2), -1/sqrt(6)],
             [        0,  2/sqrt(6)]])).T.nullspace()
[Matrix([
[-1],
[ 1],
[ 1]])]
```

All that is left to do is to normalize the vector that spans the null space. Switching its sign is legal.